# SQL Server FullText Search with Weighted Columns from Previous One Column

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

In the database on which I am attempting to create a FullText Search I need to construct a table with its column names coming from one column in a previous table. In my current implementation attempt the FullText indexing is completed on the first table `Data` and the search for the phrase is done there, then the second table with the search results is made.

The schema for the database is

```
**Players**

  Id
  PlayerName
  Blacklisted
  ...

**Details**
  Id
  Name -> FirstName, LastName, Team, Substitute, ...
  ...

**Data**
  Id
  DetailId
  PlayerId
  Content
```

`DetailId` in the table `Data` relates to `Id` in `Details`, and `PlayerId` relates to `Id` in `Players`. If there are 1k rows in `Players` and 20 rows in `Details`, then there are 20k rows in `Data`.

```
WITH RankedPlayers AS
(
    SELECT PlayerID, SUM(KT.[RANK]) AS Rnk
    FROM Data c
    INNER JOIN FREETEXTTABLE(dbo.Data, Content, '"Some phrase like team name and player name"')
    AS KT ON c. DataID = KT.[KEY]
    GROUP BY c.PlayerID 
)
…
```

Then a table is made by selecting the rows in one column. Similar to a pivot.

```
…
SELECT rc.Rnk, 
    c.PlayerID, 
    PlayerName, 
    TeamID,
    …
    (SELECT Content FROM dbo.Data data WHERE DetailID = 1 AND data.PlayerID = c.PlayerID) AS [TeamName],
    …
FROM dbo.Players c
JOIN RankedPlayers rc ON c. PlayerID = rc. PlayerID
ORDER BY rc.Rnk DESC
```

I can return a ranked table with this implementation, the aim however is to be able to produce results from weighted columns, so say the column `Playername` contributes to the rank more than say `TeamName`.

I have tried making a schema bound view with a pivot, but then I cannot index it because of the pivot. I have tried making a view of that view, but it seems the metadata is inherited, plus that feels like a clunky method.

I then tried to do it as a straight query using sub queries in the select statement, but cannot due to indexing not liking sub queries.

I then tried to join multiple times, again the index on the view doesn't like self-referencing joins.

How to do this?

I have come across this article http://developmentnow.com/2006/08/07/weighted-columns-in-sql-server-2005-full-text-search/ , and other articles here on weighted columns, however nothing as far as I can find addresses weighting columns when the columns were initially row data.

Comment: Would you roll back the solution edit, and supply it as a self-answer below? You can then click the adjacent tick mark to mark the question as resolved. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution that works really well. Put weight on the rows containing the required IDs in another table, left join that table to the table to which the full text search had been applied, and multiply the rank by the weight. Continue as previously implemented.

In code that comes out as

```
DECLARE @Weight TABLE
(
    DetailID INT,
    [Weight] FLOAT
);

INSERT INTO @Weight VALUES 
(1, 0.80),
(2, 0.80),
(3, 0.50);


WITH RankedPlayers AS
(
    SELECT PlayerID, SUM(KT.[RANK] * ISNULL(cw.[Weight], 0.10)) AS Rnk
    FROM Data c
    INNER JOIN FREETEXTTABLE(dbo.Data, Content, 'Karl Kognition C404') AS KT ON c.DataID = KT.[KEY]
    LEFT JOIN @Weight cw ON c.DetailID = cw.DetailID

    GROUP BY c.PlayerID 
)

SELECT rc.Rnk,
...
```

I'm using a temporary table here for evidence of concept. I am considering adding a column `Weights` to the table `Details` to avoid an unnecessary table and left join.